# Any jquery gallery plugins fit for this?

Tags: jquery, gallery

I'm using thumbnails,when user click,show the bigger one.

I checked some plugins,but they doesn't use thumbnails,say,it's the same image whether it looks smaller or bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery lightbox; Have an img tag with the thumbnail image, and wrap it in an anchor with href attribute pointing to the larger image.